# Why would a hacker/thief just use my credit card for Apple in-app purchase?

Tags: malware

I talked with Apple and finally I found out it was my credit card information got stolen instead of my Apple account. I looked at all my transactions and hacker/thief only made few Apple in-app purchases but nothing else, and the total cost is pretty small just around 100 US dollars, and I got refund. Any reason why the hacker/thief only did that even with my whole card information?

Answer (score 1):

Honestly, there is a surplus of credit cards out there for cheap, so it's likely to get more for your money buying dozen(s) of them and using all of them for smaller purchases in hopes of evading notice form their owners.

I have never bought stolen credit cards, but if seemingly reputable online bloggers/news sites like Krebs are to be believed, it's a remarkably easy task with no skill level required. As to the prolific availability, there is an analysis/rant section in the below article that speaks to it a bit.

http://krebsonsecurity.com/2016/01/hyatt-card-breach-hit-250-hotels-in-50-nations/